# Declare variable type for auto complete

Tags: phpstorm

I wanna get some autocomplete for some variables so i use

```
/** @var $varName \Namespace\Path\ClassName */
```

and if i have

```
ClassName {

    public function method() {
        // some code
    }

}
```

PhpStorm know to autcomplete the method `$varName->` (and now popup with autocomplete appear with `method()`)

But I don't know how to make it work if instead of `$varName` I have `$this->varName`

I try to do something like

```
/** @var $this->varName \Namespace\Path\ClassName */
```

But it's not working. It is possible to make it working?

--- Updated

```
class MyController extends GeneralController {

    use GeneralMethods;

    /**
     * @var ClassName 
     */
    protected $varName;

    public function __construct(ClassName $varName)
    {
        $this->varName = $varName;
    }

}

trait GeneralMethods {

    // ----- >> It is ok to redeclare here @varName as protected??
    /**
     * @var ClassName
     */
    protected $varName;

    public function method() {
       $this->varName = 'Some Code';
    }
}
```

Comment: *"i have `$this->varName`"* Yes and No at the same time. No, you cannot do this for 2nd level entity like that. Yes, if you typehint actual property in a class.... or use `@property` in class PHPDoc.

Comment: Check https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc-tags.md#517-var and https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc-tags.md#510-property

Comment: This is in a trait. I have a method and i wanna use in multiple controllers so i have protected $varName in controller and in trait is my method. so i dont wanna declare protected $varName in trait. It is ok?

Comment: Class/Trait/Interface -- it's the same context in this regard.

Comment: Other than that: provide more real code sample, which will make things more clear.

Comment: Ok, i will add more code.

Comment: Try `@property` in trait-level PHPDoc.

Comment: Thank you man !!!!